Create keycloak custom realm in CLI
When I start keycloak, I start with Docker from this command:
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2 start-dev

But in this way the realm is already created, and I would like to build a custom realm. So basically when I create the Docker image, I want to create the custom realm. I created it manually and then exported it partially because we can't export it fully.
So my question is: can I start keycloak locally with my custom realm?
I'm using a Mac.

You can create a custom realm by cURL command on Mac.
Also, recommend using docker compose by Docker Desktop
It helps not lose your custom realm even if the docker container is removed.
Just "docker run" and after "docker rm" to remove the container.
All of settings for the realm and user will lost.
if using docker compose with volume, you can keep the setting of Keycloak.
Demo
Save as docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.6
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Open termina on Mac
Go to Applications > Utilities > Terminal, or use Spotlight Search (Cmd + Space) and type "Terminal" to open it
Run docker compose
docker compose up -d


Open it by Browser
http://localhost:8080

Credential
username: admin
password: admin


Get master token by cURL
MASTER_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' | jq -r '.access_token')
echo $MASTER_TOKEN


Create custom realm by cURL
curl --silent --show-error -L -X POST "http://localhost:8080/admin/realms" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ""$MASTER_TOKEN" \
--data '{"realm":"demo-realm","enabled":true}'


Result


Note
The master token's default lifetime is 1 minute
So you need to call quickly after get master token
Or
Extend it more margin to testing.


thank you for this @Bench! it's so great! Is it possible to create a user as well with this realm?

Yes, create a user by REST API in here, you need remove '/auth' in URL.

but in this case I would like to start the realm with a specific client_id and a specific secret otherwise how can I get the info about this?

If not using master_token for create user, that user (with client id/secret) have to  get manage_user role in here

I mean, when I have the master token, I would also need the client_id and secret to create users right? So my point is before that when. how can I create a client_id and a pass for that specific realm?

In here, you can create client and client secret.
